# How to edit .vimrc file to replace tab with spaces?

Tags: vim, tabs, yaml, spaces

I am writing a Python script which writes some formatted data into a YAML file. I am using tabs for formatting the text, but I want the tabs to be converted into spaces when written into the YAML file. This is because my YAML file does not take tabs as valid indentation tokens.

I have tried this:

Step 1: Go to your home directory

```
cd ~
```

Step 2: Create the file

```
vim .vimrc
```

Step 3: Add the configuration stated below

```
set smartindent

set tabstop=4

set shiftwidth=4

set expandtab

:retab
```

But this does not work. The YAML file created still has tabs. The tabs are not converted to spaces.

Please suggest what changes should I make into my `.vimrc` file so that tabs are converted into spaces for valid indentation.

The Python script:

```
template = open("/home/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard/mypanel/extracted_template.yaml","w")

networks = api.neutron.network_list_for_tenant(self.request,tenant_id,params={}) 

for n in range(0,len(networks)):
      n_name = networks[n]['name']
      print>>template,"\tprivate_net%d:"%n,"\n\t type: OS::Neutron::Net","\n\t properties:","\n\t  name:",n_name
```

Comment: Do you use any plugins that could modify the tabs settings at run time?

Comment: This is not a vim problem. This is a problem in Python if you want the initial output to contain spaces instead of tabs. Please show us the Python source.

Comment: I have successfully converted tabs into spaces by following what @byaruhaf has suggested. But the problem is still the same. The converted tabs are still treated as tabs which is not a valid indentation token for YAML files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert tabs to spaces use the commands below in the order below:

```
:set noexpandtab
:retab!
:set expandtab
:retab!
```

I go this answer from watching this vim cast.
[Tidying Whitespace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/)

Vim can already detect the file type yaml so you can use that to replace all TAB's in your YAML file add this your .vimrc

```
:autocmd FileType yaml execute  ':silent! %s#^\t\+#\=repeat(" ", len(submatch(0))*' . &ts . ')'
```

Comment: What I am looking for is not that I open the file and then enter the command :retab! to convert tabs into spaces. I need to make this automated. I want when I open the files, the tabs are already converted to spaces. For this I need to edit the .vimrc file for permanent settings but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: modified the answer to include an autocmd for your vimrc

Comment: Even this is not working for me. I have added these lines to .vimrc but the tab is not converted to spaces.

Comment: Changed the autocmd to search and replace all tabs for a yaml file, can you try this and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 4):

Create a .vimrc file in your home directory if it does not exist. Edit the file and add following lines

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Answer (score 0):

To manage YAML files correctly, edit */etc/vim/vimrc.local* or *.vimrc* or other VIM configuration file adding the following line:

```
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab nocindent smartindent
```